# play! framework ENUM and Groovy problem

Tags: java, templates, groovy, enums, playframework

I have something like the following-

**Woman.java**

```
...
@Entity
public class Woman extends Model {

    public static enum Outcome {
        ALIVE, DEAD, STILL_BIRTH, LIVE_BIRTH, REGISTER
    }
    ...
}
```

**File.java**

```
...
@Entity
public class Form extends Model {
    ...
    public Outcome autoCreateEvent;
    ...
}
```

Create.html

```
#{select "autoCreateEvent", items:models.Woman.Outcome.values(), id:'autoCreateEvent' /}
```

It saves ENUM value in DB, which is OK. But, when I reload/edit then the problem rises. Because it uses ALIVE, DEAD, etc. as the value for options so it can't show the list properly.

Any Insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question properly you want to use the `valueProperty` and `labelProperty` to set the proper values in the `option`. Something like:

```
#{select "autoCreateEvent", items:models.Woman.Outcome.values(), valueProperty:'ordinal', labelProperty: 'name', id:'autoCreateEvent' /}
```

EDIT:

For this to work you will need to tweak the enum a bit, like this:

```
public enum Outcome {
  A,B;

  public int getOrdinal() {
     return ordinal();
  }

}
```

The reason is that Play #{select} expects getters in the `valueProperty` and `labelProperty` params, and when not found defaults to the enum `toString`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply and I thought it should work but it doesn't. Can you please go to this link and search for 'valueProperty', they have commented that part - http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-filterpane/tags/RELEASE_0_7/grails-app/taglib/com/zeddware/grails/plugins/filterpane/FilterTagLib.groovy

Comment: @rifat you gave a link to grails, not play framework... what error do you get?

Comment: no error! but it gives wrong output

    <option value="ALIVE">ALIVE</option>

whereas I expected

    <option value="0">ALIVE</option>

Comment: though I'm still in trouble but what you said is OK :)

Answer (score 1):

To add to previous answer, add this to your Enum declaration:

```
public String getLabel() {
    return play.i18n.Messages.get(name());
}
```

Make sure to use the following declaration:

```
#{select "[field]", items:models.[Enum].values(), valueProperty:'name', labelProperty: 'label' /}
```

You can also add this in the Enum:

```
    @Override
public String toString() {
    return getLabel();
}
```

Which will be useful if you want to display the internationalized value in your view file (since toString is being called automatically when displayed) but function name() uses toString() so you will have to bind valueProperty to another function, as follow:

```
public String getLabel(){
    return toString();
}

public String getKey() {
    return super.toString();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return Messages.get(name());
}
```

And the #select use:

```
#{select "[field]", items:models.[Enum].values(), value:flash.[field], valueProperty:'key', labelProperty: 'label' /}
```